# JS classList.remove() working irregularly during drag events

Tags: javascript, dom, web-applications, drag-and-drop

I am trying to build a drag and drop system, which highlights available dropzones when dragging a dragitem over them.
I do this by adding a class to a dropzone, when a suitable drag item hovers over it.
However, when the drag item leaves ("dragleave" event), sometimes the class does not get removed and the highlight says.
What could be a possible reason for this behavior and how do I fix it?

Example of the bug:

[image: bug in a gif]

Code excerpt:

```js
// drag events
  element.addEventListener("dragenter", (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    checkBacktrack(event.target);
  });

  element.addEventListener("dragleave", (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.target === nodeStack.at(-1)) {
      popNodeStack();
    }
  });


// Node stack functions (nodeStack = stack of nodes to keep track):

  const checkBacktrack = (element) => {
    for (let i = nodeStack.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      const topNode = nodeStack.at(-1);
      if (topNode === element) {
        return true;
      } else if (topNode.contains(element)) {
        pushNodeStack(element);
        return true;
      } else {
        popNodeStack();
      }
    }
    pushNodeStack(element);
    return false;
  };

  const popNodeStack = () => {
    const removedNode = nodeStack.pop();
    tryPopHighlight(removedNode);
  };

  const pushNodeStack = (element) => {
    nodeStack.push(element);
    tryPushHighlight(element);
  };

//Highlight functions (highlightStack = stack of elements to highlight):

  const tryPushHighlight = (element) => {
    if (_isValidDropzone(element)) {
      pushHighlight(element);
    }
  };

  const tryPopHighlight = (element) => {
    if (highlightStack.at(-1) === element) {
      popHighlight();
    }
  };

  const pushHighlight = (element) => {
    element.classList.add("drag-under-item");
    const currentHighlight = highlightStack.at(-1);
    if (currentHighlight) {
      currentHighlight.classList.remove("drag-under-item");
    }
    highlightStack.push(element);
  };

  const popHighlight = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const removedHighlight = highlightStack.pop();
      if (removedHighlight)
        removedHighlight.classList.remove("drag-under-item");

      const newHighlight = highlightStack.at(-1);
      if (newHighlight) newHighlight.classList.add("drag-under-item");
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Literally 1 minute after posting this I found the issue.
I moved nodeStack and highlightStack out of the function body into a static context, now everything is working like magic...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).